# Adding and finding rcu node from a rcu list

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, rcu

I am trying to add `rcu` node into `rcu_list` by calling a function , `hlist_add_head_rcu`, with `rcu_list`'s own lock and `spin_lock`.

After that, i need to check whether the `rcu` node is on pending for assigning into `rcu_list` before calling  a reclaimer function callback.

**Is there way to check whether the `rcu` node is on pending yet ?**

Actually, i tried to check `rcu_list` by calling a function , `hlist_for_each_entry_safe`, and iterating list with `spin_lock` of `rcu_list`'s own lock.

Of course, I thought that it was not good way and it would be illegal way of the `rcu` law.

I hope to know how to resolve this problem with efficient way.

Comment: Why do you need to know whether the node is on pending? Do you want to know the pending state form reader-side, or from writer-side?

Comment: Well. I try to find a way to remove the node which is on pending before calling a reclaimer function callback.